# Pandas Dataframe to Dictionary with Multiple Keys

Tags: python, r, dictionary, pandas, nested

I am currently working with a dataframe consisting of a column of 13 letter strings ('13mer') paired with ID codes ('Accession') as such:

[image: Original Data Frame]

However, I would like to create a dictionary in which the Accession codes are the keys with values being the 13mers associated with the accession so that it looks as follows:

```
{'JO2176': ['IGY....', 'QLG...', 'ESS...', ...],
 'CYO21709': ['IGY...', 'TVL...',.............],
 ...}
```

Which I've accomplished using this code:

```
Accession_13mers = {}
for group in grouped:
    Accession_13mers[group[0]] = []
    for item in group[1].iteritems():
        Accession_13mers[group[0]].append(item[1])
```

However, now I would like to go back through and iterate through the keys for each Accession code and run a function I've defined as find_match_position(reference_sequence, 13mer) which finds the 13mer in in a reference sequence and returns its position. I would then like to append the position as a value for the 13mer which will be the key.

If anyone has any ideas for how I can expedite this process that would be extremely helpful.

Thanks,

Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new dictionary, whose values are another dictionary. Essentially a nested dictionary.

```
position_nmers = {}
for key in H1_Access_13mers:
    position_nmers[key] = {} # replicate key, val in new dictionary, as a dictionary
    for value in H1_Access_13mers[key]:
        position_nmers[key][value] = # do something
```

To introspect the dictionary and make sure it's okay:

```
print position_nmers
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the groupby more cleanly by unpacking:

```
d = {}
for key, s in df.groupby('Accession')['13mer']:
    d[key] = list(s)
```

This also makes it much clearer where you should put your function!

... However, I think that it might be better suited to an enumerate:

```
d2 = {}
for pos, val in enumerate(df['13mer']):
    d2[val] = pos
```